# Should I always check member pointers for nullptr?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it bad to do something like this? (not checking for nullptr inside the draw() function before doing operations with the object pointer)

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
    SomeClass(Object& someValidObject)
    {
       object = &someValidObject;
    }

    void draw()
    {
        object->draw();
    }

    Object* object = nullptr;
}
```

Or should I always check for nullptr before calling operations in the object, even though the constructor is for sure going to make the pointer point to something?

```
void draw()
{
   if(object != nullptr) 
      object->draw?
}
```

Comment: "even though the constructor is for sure going to make the pointer point to something?" What if I pass to you an Object created on the stack, which will be destroyed as soon as it goes out of scope? Yes, this is **very** bad

Comment: Isn't it better to just use a smart pointer and let that do the dirty work?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq, a smart pointer could also be invalid when just simply considering SomeClass::draw.

Comment: Your sample will not compile. You can only assign value to a non-static class member in a method or in a constructor in c++. Aside from that, this approach is called 'aggregation' and is used quite often. Your code doesn't really address the problem of null pointer validation. If somebody is using it like that: SomeClass sc(NULL); Calling it someValidObject doesn't make it valid.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi -- that will not produce a null pointer.

Comment: `object = &someValidObject` is bad design because the caller might have supplied an object with a shorter lifetime than the `SomeClass` instance being initialized, resulting in a dangling pointer when that first object dies

Comment: @M.M This is a perfectly fine design. Sure, I could make it more safe, but that means making it more complex, potentially adding runtime and maintenance overhead. If I instead decide to require my clients to keep the object alive for me, that is a valid design decision.

Comment: @PeteBecker No, it will not produce a nullptr. It will produce a code that has the appearance of being solid when in fact is UB. If you prefer it this way... I can't object to a matter of taste.

Answer (score 4):

Depends what you are trying to protect against.

As was pointed out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39715484/is-it-bad-to-do-something-like-this#comment66728842_39715484) already, you cannot reliably check for dangling pointers, so if the passed `Object` goes out of scope before your `SomeClass`, bad things will happen.

So the only thing that you can reliably check is whether the pointer is `nullptr`, but as you have noticed yourself, currently the constructor makes that next to impossible. However, as long as your `object` member variable is `public` like it is now, the user could in theory reach in there and set it to `nullptr`. You can make that harder by making the member `private` and use a setter which rejects `nullptr` values (or simply takes a reference, like the constructor). In such a design, `object != nullptr` can be considered a *class invariant*, that is a condition that is true before and after every member function call (from the time after construction until before destruction).

So how do we break a class invariant? As a client, we could violate a function's preconditions and thus bring the class into an undefined state. With a class as simple as your sample, this is hard to do, as the functions do not really have preconditions. But let's assume for arguments sake, you were to add a setter like this:

```
// Precondition: obj must point to a valid Object.
// That object must be kept alive for the lifetime of the class,
// otherwise the behavior is undefined.
void setObject(Object* obj)
{
    object = obj;
}
```

Now this is somewhat subtle. The code allows us to pass a `nullptr` here, but the documentation explicitly forbids it. If we pass a `nullptr` or have the passed object die before our `SomeClass`, we violate the contract of that class. But this contract is not enforced in code, it's only in the comments.

The important thing to realize here is that there are conditions that cannot be checked in code. We can check for `nullptr`, but we cannot check for dangling pointers. Sometimes checks would be possible, but are undesirable due to high runtime costs (eg. check that a range is sorted for a binary search). Once we realize this it becomes clear that we have some wiggle room here as a class designer. Since we anyway cannot make things 100% bullet-proof, should we check anything at all? Sure, we can check for `nullptr` everywhere, but that means paying the runtime overhead for checking what is basically a programming error.

What if I don't want to pay this overhead in production builds? Maybe I would like my debugger to catch it if I make a mistake during development, but I don't want my clients to have to pay for the check later after release.

So what you are really looking for is an assert:

```
void draw()
{
    assert(object);
    object->draw();
}
```

The decision whether to check something in an assert (or not at all) or have a proper runtime check that is part of the contract is not an easy one. It is more often than not a philosophical question. John Lakos gave an excellent [talk about this at CppCon 2014](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1QhtXRMp3Hg) if you want to dig deeper.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is a matter of taste. But *I* think it is good practice for the sake of maintainability to express expectations inside the code (and as code); therefore I would rather write:

```
void draw()
{
   if(object == nullptr) { /* throw some exception */ }

   object->draw()
}
```

**Edit**

As suggested in the comments of my answer it is usually not enough to only check for *null* pointer in C++. Indeed, a pointer can be non-null yet invalid (this is called a dangling pointer). This happens when `object` is destroyed before the `draw` function is called.

Comment: Or adjust your answer explaining why this is a wrong practice.

Answer (score 1):

> even though the constructor is for sure going to make the pointer point to something

That's true for freshly constructed instances. But how long does that guarantee last? Consider following:

```
Object o;
SomeClass s(o);
s.object = nullptr
s.draw(); // oops
```

**Somebody** has to guarantee that the pointer isn't null. Sure, you can always do a check in `draw`. That works. In that case the guaranteer is `draw` itself. Then the preconditions of `draw` are: `object` points to a valid object and meets the preconditions of `Object::draw` or `object` points to null.

Alternatively, you can state that `object != nullptr` is a requirement (simply by requiring that `object` points to a valid object that meets the preconditions of `Object::draw`). In that case, the guaranteer is the caller of `draw`. Then you do not need to check the null.

The advantage of former is that the function has more relaxed preconditions which are harder to violate by programmer error. The disadvantage is performance penalty (possibly marginal in this case) of possibly redundant check.

The advantage of latter is runtime performance benefit in cases where `object != nullptr` is already guaranteed by the caller. The disadvantage is that violating the precondition by programmer error is easier. This can be mitigated by using an assertion that allows catching bugs when developing and optimal performance in production.

The latter alternative can be significantly improved by making `object` private. Then `object != nullptr` can be considered a class invariant. If the invariance is guaranteed, there is no need for runtime check, and only the implementer of the class can accidentally violate the preconditions. Such violation can be easily caught using assertions and unit tests.

---

The result of violating any of the preconditions in either approach is **undefined behaviour**. The preconditions cannot be expressed in C++, but are simply part of the documentation.

The precondition that `object` must point to a valid object is much trickier to guarantee since `SomeClass` isn't responsible for the lifetime of `object`. To make the guarantee simpler, consider the possibility of using smart pointers, or avoid indirection entirely.

Answer (score 1):

It all comes down to the idea of a contract. If your pointer can reasonably be null you must check fir it. If the pointer should never be null, don't check for it, you are just wasting cpu cycles. Besides, what should the the behavior be if the pointer is null.

There is a case for use of an assert. It only appears in debug code and conveys to your user tgat the contract is that the pointer should never be null.