# Checking pointers before using? necessity and alternatives, C++ UE4

Tags: c++, pointers, unreal-engine4

I'm new to UE4, and I encountered the general pattern of checking each pointer before using it, for example:

```
AActor *pActor = getOwner(); 
if(pActor){
   pActor->SOME_FUNCTION();
}
```

I'm aware to the fact that crashes are awful in terms of user experience, and that it is always advised to write code with maximum robustness, but are there well-known cases in which the pattern is really useful? (for example in theoretically safe settings, such as a pointer set to `GetOwner()`).

And if so, are there any common alternatives for this? (perhaps making use of smart pointers?)

EDIT:
In my question I wanted to get an answer regarding UE4 specifically, since I encountered a source relating to UE4 only, which advised me to check pointers, although I wasn't sure about its necessity and in which pattern.

Comment: what is getOwner? Is it expected to return the null pointer? What is happening after the branch?

Comment: @SergeyA GetOwner is a UE4 function, which is expected to return a pointer to the owning actor of a component.

Comment: Question is, are you expecting to have components without actors? What does it mean?

Comment: By the way, a comment by a staff on [this question](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/422693/using-getowner-crash-the-editor.html) suggest that `getOwner` can indeed return a null pointer. And there are no real alternatives to checking as you are receiving a raw pointer - smart pointers would not help here in any way.

Comment: @SergeyA Indeed. For example a Pawn (which is the player's body, and also inherits from Actor), has a Physics Handle component for grabbing items.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I always check member pointers for nullptr?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39715484/should-i-always-check-member-pointers-for-nullptr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not absolutely guaranteed to receive a valid pointer from a function that returns a pointer, you need to check that pointer. In the case of libraries that are black boxes (you don't own the code), you can perhaps take the word of the library author that the pointer will always be valid, but based on a comment above, that does not appear to be the case here.

Interestingly enough, in the C++ Core Guidelines: http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#S-gsl

There is a template in the Guidelines Support Library called `not_null<T>` which can be used to encapsulate a pointer to provide the guarantee that the pointer is never NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is tagged `C++`, there is an obvious alternative for a pointer that must not be `NULL`: a reference. (see [basic considerations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in) or [technical details](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization) for more information).

If you stay with pointers, you have - by definition - to deal with the possibility that each and everyone of them is `NULL`.

---

Update: A pretty silly example:

```
AActor & get_existing_owner() 
{
    AActor * pActor = getOwner(); 
    check(pActor);
    return *pActor;
}
```

Please note that this changes the behavior of your code in case `getOwner` actually returns `nullptr` some time (cf. [UE Assertions](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/Assertions/index.html)). Then you could write somewhere else (without further checks):

```
get_existing_owner().some_function();
```

Obviously above `get_existing_...` checking method could be generealized / reused for other pointers.

Comment: You mean that I should assign each pointer I try to get from a function, to a reference ?

Comment: @GoldenSpecOps: Nope, that won't help a bit: You'll get undefined behavior if you convert a `nullptr` to a reference. The conversion will likely work fine (it's a noop as far as the machine is concerned), but some time later, you'll get the same crash as with the pointer. If you want to get safety out of using references, you must check the pointer *before* converting it to a reference.

Comment: No. You can't do much about the return value (eg. pointer) of some API-function. But you can use references in your code. I'll update with an example...

Comment: @cmaster so basically using references doesn't contribute anything since I'll still have to check each pointer

Comment: Dropping the checks will abort the program whenever the assumption is ever not met. This changes the code!

Comment: Please at least use `nullptr` instead of the "old" macro `NULL`. The Unreal Engine Coding Standard [strongly suggests it](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/Development/CodingStandard/#nullptr)

Comment: Also by default Unreal Engine comes with disabled exception handling (see e.g.: [this question](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/264921/cannot-use-try-with-exceptions-disabled.html)) - so your *"silly example"*  won't even work too well

Comment: @GoldenSpecOps: Yes, and no: Yes, you still have to do the checking when you convert a pointer to a reference. However, using references moves the problem: Now it's up to the code converting the pointer to the reference to check the pointer, not to each and every bit of code using the reference. So, using references may help reducing the problem. It's basically like this: When some code produces a reference, it declares by using a reference, that it has already done the `nullptr` check, and that other code does not need to repeat it.

Comment: @cmaster I think you solved two of my problems at the same time. After getting the general sense that there's no running away from validating every pointer, I ran into a problem where I would use a pointer several times withing a code segment, and I thought I'd have to check it every single time. So basically checking it once and dereferencing it into a ref would significantly reduce the work (in case I understood you correctly)

Comment: @GoldenSpecOps if you already perform the check it doesn't make much difference whether you store it in a reference or pointer (except for a minor syntax difference). The usual pattern is to either wrap all access to a pointer in a single `if(ptr)` or have one check right after fetching the pointer and returning/asserting if it is null.

Comment: @UnholySheep Oh, so I shouldn't go for the "paranoid" pattern, which means that I assume a pointer can get corrupted between any two lines of code (and hence check before every use)?

Comment: @GoldenSpecOps no, as long as it's within the same frame a pointed to object should never become deallocated or "corrupted" - if it does then you would have some massive threading issues (and you wouldn't be able to check for it particularly well either - the pointer you store would not contain the"updated" value - it would just point to an invalid location in memory). Note that you should not store pointers to objects that you are not the owner of for more than one frame - that could cause issues (instead request the pointer when you need it/once per frame)